# how to extract mfcc using python

Tags: python

some help, please.
there are many people who use the first method and others used the second one. I need to know why they use the transpose and if it is right !!

```
method1:mfccs=np.mean(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=X, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40), axis=0)

methode2:mfccs=np.mean(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=X, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40).T, axis=0)
```

Comment: Please add some more code so people could run your example, maybe some general explanation about the problem you have will help as well. Add tags of  [librosa] and [numpy] to get more users to look at your question. I'm sure someone will help soon :)

Comment: Some context would be great. If the data is 2D, method 1 computes the mean per column while method 2 computes the mean per row. If you don't know why the row or column mean is important, please ask the people who use these methods.